# Burninate [loadmask]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Title says it all, 14 questions, 0 followers.  Just be sure to hide the [loadmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loadmask) after burnination:

```
loadMask.show();
burninate(loadMask.tag);
loadMask.hide();
```

Comment: Not bent on the burnination (actually, do we need this tag?) but some cleanup/disambiguation might be in order.

Answer (score 4):

No.

[Ext.LoadMask](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.LoadMask.html) and [jquery-loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) are legitimate things.  It may do to separate these two into distinct, separate things, but burninate?  I'm going to have to call the fire extinguisher out on this one.

Comment: That exist two things with the same name yet different, merits some kind of action, and no-action is not the correct action.

Comment: Load masks be they ExtJS or JQuery may be "things" but is anybody an expert in LoadMasks?

Comment: I'm sure that there are enough people out there that make use of those specific technologies to warrant its existence.  The single tag itself does need to be split out, but that doesn't mean that the tag itself shouldn't be there.

Comment: What about moving them into separate tags? [ext-loadmask] and [jquery-loadmask]?

Comment: Hmm, most of the posts were already tagged with either [extjs], and the couple ones without were related to [extjs]. There was only one which was tagged [jquery]. So agree with the assessment that there's nothing needed to be done.